# How can I validate WOPI is working on OOS on-prem using PowerShell or REST?

Tags: powershell, rest, sharepoint-2016, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I'm trying to trouble shoot our on-prem OOS and read about the WopiTest framework for Office 365 at [MS Docs - WOPI Validation application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/online/build-test-ship/validator#interactive-wopi-validation)

Does Office Online Server have a corresponding framework for validating the WOPI framework?
(I couldn't find any REST calls at https://officeonline-onprem/hosting/discovery)

In that case, how can this be done using PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod`?

I do have a method to call OOS WOPI-rendering using PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest`, but since iFrames isn't exposed, I can't tell if rendering was performed or not.
(Well, if I use another tool and sniff the answer I can get the iFrame URL:s returned. But that seems a bit overkill.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well, if I use another tool and sniff the answer I can get the iFrame URL:s returned. But that seems a bit overkill.

I am afraid that's the only way to do it with the on-prem OOS as it doesn't expose any testing URLs such as the cloud version does.